# Can たら be used like "ever since?"

Tags: grammar

For instance,

日本に来たら、毎日寿司を食べました。

Does this make sense grammatically? I tried to translate: "Ever since I came to Japan, I've been eating sushi everyday."

Comment: へえ、すごいお金持ちですねー。

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to say "日本に来てから、毎日寿司を食べています" so the final verb also changes a bit, indicating you are still eating that delicious sushi daily.